# Regular expression returns true on value that does not occur in list of options

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to see if there's a exact match on `/venues` within the list of options:

`/themeparks` OR `special` OR `/boats` OR `/mobile` OR `/historical+venues`.

But these expressions always returns `true` for the match:

```
Dim urlMatch As Match
urlMatch = Regex.Match("/venues",
                "(^/themeparks|^/special|^/boats|^/mobile|^/historical\+venues|)/[a-zA-Z]",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

urlMatch = Regex.Match("^/venues",
                "(^/themeparks|^/special|^/boats|^/mobile|^/historical\+venues|)/[a-zA-Z]",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

urlMatch = Regex.Match("/venues",
            "(^\/themeparks|^\/special|^\/boats|^\/mobile|^\/historical\+venues|)/[a-zA-Z]",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

urlMatch = Regex.Match("/venues",
            "(^\/themeparks|^\/special|^\/boats|^\/mobile|^\/historical\+^venues|)/[a-zA-Z]",
            RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

What am  I missing?

Comment: Your regex is not matching `/venues` for me. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nB6qL7)

Comment: Thanks. I saw you added escaping of the `/` character in the URL. So I added a new test to my post, but still I get `true` as a result

Comment: As @WashingtonGuedes says, `(xxx|)/[a-zA-Z]` will match `/v` because the last alternation says it can match nothing, so it goes on to the next construct `/[a-zA-Z]` to find a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improved regex:

```
^\/(?:themeparks|special|boats|mobile|historical\+venues)\/[a-zA-Z]
```

What changed?

1. Look that `^\/` was written only once.
2. Look that `(?:...)` instead of `(...)` doesn't group.
3. Look that I removed last pipe `|` avoiding empty matches in the `(?:...)`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/dB2zW1/1)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But what exactly do you mean by the 2nd point?

Comment: @Flo. Try in the live regex using `(...)` instead of `(?:...)`. You will see that the regex engine will _store_ the content inside it.

Comment: Ah, I see. And I'm assuming `(?:...)` instead of `(...)` will result in a (albeit slight) performance improvement?

Comment: @Flo. For a big one input, yes it will.